# Irreducible linear set of quadratics over $\Bbb F_p$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Given $a,b\in\Bbb F_p$, denote $$S(a,b)=\big\{(a+\beta)x^2+(b-\beta)x+1\in\Bbb F_p[x]:\beta\in\Bbb F_p\big\}.$$

Denote $$S(a,b)_\mathrm{red}=\big\{g(x)\in S(a,b):g(x)\text{ is reducible}\big\}.$$

What is a good upper and lower bound for $$E_{\max}=\max_{\substack{a,b\in\Bbb F_p  }}\big|S(a,b)_\mathrm{red}\big|?$$

What is a good upper and lower bound for $$E_{\min}=\min_{\substack{a,b\in\Bbb F_p  }}\big|S(a,b)_\mathrm{red}\big|?$$

What is a good upper and lower bound for $$E_\mathrm{avg}=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{a,b\in\Bbb F_p}} \big| S(a,b)_\mathrm{red} \big|}{p}?$$

Is there sharp estimates?

Can $E_\mathrm{avg}$ or $E_{\max}$ be $O(\log p)$ or both just $\Theta(\frac{p}2)$?

Can $E_{\min}=0$ be possible? If so with what probability?

Comment: A lot can be said. The 1st observation I want to make is that the set $S(a,b)$ only depends on the sum $a+b$:
$$S(a,b)=\{f(x)=a_2x^2+a_1x+1\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]\mid f(1)=1+a+b\}.$$
The second observation is that, barring the case $a_2=0, a_1=a+b$ (or $\beta=-a$), the polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if its reciprocal polynomial
$$\tilde{f}(x)=x^2+a_1x+a_2$$ is irreducible. This translates it to a well-studied class of problems: distribution of irreducible monic polynomials (of a fixed degree) among cosets of ideals of polynomials.

Comment: (cont'd) Here we need to study the distribution of irreducible quadratics among the cosets of the ideal $I=\langle x-1\rangle$, because the focus is on polynomials with a known value at $x=1$. The general result is a precise analogue of Dirichlet's result of equidistribution of prime numbers among cosets $a+m\Bbb{Z}$ such that $\gcd(a,m)=1$. Here the polynomials in $I$ itself are obviously all reducible, but the irreducible ones are to be nearly equidistributed. This theme is studied, IMO in a very accessible way in M. Rosen's book *Number Theory in Function Fields*, GTM 210, Springer.

Comment: For example, bounds for the deviation from equidistribution are given there (among many other nice analogies between integers and univariate polynomials over a finite field). Granted, the general results are asymptotic in nature - not about polynomials of a fixed degree. But, this is a very special case, so I want to think about it, even at the risk of exposing my stupidity for not seeing the answer right away :-)

Comment: Thank you very much here. Waiting for your post:)

Comment: corrected $p(p-1)$

Comment: Avg for this also should be $p-2$ then since both problem here and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419753/counting-points-on-curve?noredirect=1#comment2893596_1419753 are same

Comment: Sorry about suggesting to replace the denominator $p(p-1)$ with $p$. I was thinking in terms of the probability of a polynomial in $S(a,b)$ being reducible. I didn't realize that you were summing over all pairs $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it goes. Recalling some observations from the comments, and then adding more steps:

1. The set $S(a,b)$ only depends on the value of $a+b$, because
   $$S(a,b)=\{f(x)=a_2x^2+a_1x+1\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]\mid f(1)=1+a+b\}.$$
2. Ignoring the case $a_2=0$ (i.e. when $f(x)$ is linear), the polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if when its reciprocal polynomial
   $$
   \tilde{f}(x):=x^2f(\frac1x)=x^2+a_1x+a_2
   $$
   is irreducible.
3. The polynomial $\tilde{f}(x)$ is irreducible, if and only if the polynomial
   $$g(x):=f(x+1)=x^2+(a_1+2)x+(a_1+a_2+1)$$
   is irreducible.
4. Therefore there is a bijection from the set of irreducible quadratic polynomials in $S(a,b)$ to the set of monic irreducible quadratic polynomials
   $$g(x)=x^2+Ax+B$$
   with $B=a+b+1$.
5. Altogether there are exactly $(p^2-p)/2$ monic quadratic irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$. These are exactly the minimal polynomials of elements of the set $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}\setminus\Bbb{F}_p$. There are $p^2-p$ such elements, but the conjugate pairs, $\alpha$ and $\alpha^p$, share the same minimal polynomial.
6. The constant term of such a minimal polynomial
   $$m_\alpha(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^p)=x^2-[\alpha+\alpha^p]x+\alpha^{p+1}$$
   is known as the *norm* of $\alpha$, $N(\alpha)=\alpha^{p+1}\in\Bbb{F}_p$.
7. The norm map $N:\Bbb{F}_{p^2}^*\to\Bbb{F}_p^*$ is a surjective homomorphism of cyclic groups. A calculation of orders of theses groups immediately tells us that $\operatorname{Ker}N$ is a subgroup of size $p+1$. Therefore any non-zero $B\in\Bbb{F}_p$ occurs as the norm of exactly $p+1$ elements of $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$.
8. For all $c\in\Bbb{F}_p$ we have $N(c)=c^2$. So such a $B\in\Bbb{F}_p^*$ occurs as the norm of an element of $\Bbb{F}_p$ if and only if it is a square in $\Bbb{F}_p^*$. When that is the case we have $B=N(c)$ for exactly two elements $c\in\Bbb{F}_p$, namely $c=\pm\sqrt{B}$.
9. The number of irreducible quadratics $g(x)$ from step 4 is thus equal to $(p+1)/2$ when $B=a+b+1$ is a non-square, and $(p-1)/2$ when $B$ is a non-zero square in $\Bbb{F}_p$.
10. Therefore the number of irreducible quadratic polynomials in the set $S(a,b)$ is
    $$
    |S(a,b)|_{irred}=\begin{cases}
    0&,\ \text{if $a+b+1=0$,}\\
    \dfrac{p+1}2&,\ \text{if $a+b+1$ is a non-zero square of $\Bbb{F}_p$},\\
    \dfrac{p-1}2&,\ \text{if $a+b+1$ is a non-square of $\Bbb{F}_p$}.
    \end{cases}.
    $$

I'm sure you can do the rest.

Comment: Is there any other case left?

Comment: I don't think so. Have you seen instances when the number of irreducibles in $S(a,b)$ was something else?

Comment: Reduction modulo $p$ takes a reducible polynomial of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ to a reducible one, but a polynomial irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ may become reducible when reducted. For example $x^2+1=(x-2)(x+2)$ modulo $5$.